# v-slot is not compatible with nuxt version 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Before, I coded nuxt beta + used vuetify's UI.
This is my custom text-field component

```
<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<template>
   <v-text-field class="text-field" v-bind="$attrs" variant="solo">
     <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" #[name]="slotData">
       <slot :name="name" v-bind="slotData" />
     </template>
   </v-text-field>
</template>
```

But after I updated the nuxt version to the official nuxt 3 version, it got an error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type 'Readonly<{ message?: ((arg: VMessageSlot) => VNode<RendererNode, RendererElement, { [key: string]: any; }>[]) | undefined; clear?: (() => VNode<...>[]) | undefined; ... 8 more ...; counter?: ((arg: VCounterSlot) => VNode<...>[]) | undefined; }>'.
   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Readonly<{ message?: ((arg: VMessageSlot) => VNode<RendererNode, RendererElement, { [key: string]: any; }>[]) | undefined; clear?: (() => VNode<...>[]) | undefined; ... 8 more ...; counter?: ((arg: VCounterSlot) => VNode<...>[]) | undefined; }>'.ts(7053)
```

in #[name]

Can anyone help me fix this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Vue 3 with the Composition API and TypeScript, and the error is related to the type definition for the $slots object. The error is indicating that TypeScript cannot determine the correct type for the keys of $slots when you are using it in the v-for loop.

To resolve this issue, you can provide a type assertion for the keys of $slots to let TypeScript know that they are of type string or number. Here's how you can do it:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
// Import the appropriate types from Vue
import { VNode, RendererNode, RendererElement, VMessageSlot, VCounterSlot } 
from 'vue';

</script>

<template>
 <v-text-field class="text-field" v-bind="$attrs" variant="solo">
  <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" :key="name" #[name]="slotData">
    <slot :name="name" v-bind="slotData" />
  </template>
 </v-text-field>
</template>
```

In this example, I imported the necessary types from Vue and used the :key="name" binding in the v-for loop to help TypeScript infer the correct type for the name variable. This should resolve the issue you're facing. Make sure to adjust the import statement based on the actual structure of your Vue setup.

Comment: Actually, I followed the key in v-for but in #[name] I still got an error related to not being able to determine the type.

Answer (score -1):

The error you are encountering is a TypeScript error related to indexing objects using a string or number when TypeScript can't verify that the object has an index signature that includes those types.

In the context of Vue 3 and TypeScript, this often happens when dealing with $slots and trying to access specific slot names dynamically.

Here is a common workaround:

```js
<template>
  <v-text-field class="text-field" v-bind="$attrs" variant="solo">
    <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" :key="name" :slot="name">
      <!-- Use scoped slot instead of #[name] -->
      <slot :name="name" v-bind="slotProps[name]" />
    </template>
  </v-text-field>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps(['class', 'variant']);

// Access slots via $slots and define the specific slots you expect
const { message, clear, counter } = $slots;
const slotProps = { message, clear, counter };
</script>
```

In this example:

I've replaced the #[name] syntax with :slot="name" and used slotProps[name] to access the dynamic slot content.
We've defined specific slots (message, clear, counter) and used them in the slotProps object.
By explicitly defining the slots you expect and using slotProps[name], you provide TypeScript with more information about the structure of the object, which can help resolve the indexing issue.

Make sure to customize this solution based on your actual slots and their expected names. The key is to be explicit about the slots you're working with and use that information to provide TypeScript with the necessary context.